# How can I add a different value to each item in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt a modified Vigenère cipher text. I am unfamiliar with Mathematica, so I need some guidance. Here is what I want:

```
modifiedVigenere[ciphertext_, keylength_]:= *insert code here*
```

Here is what I want the code to do. First, convert the ciphertext to numbers mod 26. I already have a command which will do this.

```
stringToNumbers[string_] := ToCharacterCode[StringReplace[ToUpperCase[string], 
  RegularExpression["[^A-Z]"] -> ""]] - 65
```

Then I want to modify the numbers based on the keylength. Let's say the string changes to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. Then, let's say the keylength is 3. I want to subtract 0 from the first three entries in the list, 1 from the second three, 2 from the third three, and then 3 from the final three (in this case, only the number 10). The resulting string would look like this: `{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7}`.

I would then change the numbers back into a string with the following command:

```
numbersToString[list_] := 
  FromCharacterCode[
    Select[list, Function[x, IntegerQ[x] && x >= 0 && x <26]] + 65
  ]
```

If anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `stringToNumbers` and `numbersToString` you can also use the functions `LetterNumber` and `FromLetterNumber`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

```
modifiedVigenere[ciphertext_, keylength_] := StringJoin[
    FromLetterNumber[
        LetterNumber[
            ciphertext
        ] - Floor[
            Range[
                0,
                StringLength[ciphertext] - 1
            ]/keylength
        ]
    ]
]
```

This produces

```
modifiedVigenere["abcdefghij", 3]  (* "abccdeefgg" *)
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NathanielLackey if you find an answer valuable & useful, it’s always better to make that checkmark turn green by accepting the answer :) not only does it provide others in the future a nice and easy way to see if a problem is solved or not, it gives the answering party a good bit of points ;D